# android-can't run a code one a day

Tags: android, android-service

This is a code that i'm using for running a service once a day . 
the problem is this , after 24h , the service keeps calling every 10 to 15 min .

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400, pendingIntent);
```

I think I'm using a bad code .Could you give me a better code for runnig a service once or twice a day

thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval parameter to `setRepeating` represents millis. It should be 86400000 to get it right.

You are now programming an alarm to start first execution 24h past the current time, but with a period of 86400 millis (less than two minutes).

Morale of the story:

- Always read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) before using an API.
- Use [AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY) instead of your own magic numbers